# What is the point of this? If $f:X\to Y $ is an homeomorphism then $\forall A\subset X, f|_A:A\to f(A)$ is an homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology

What is the point of saying this

If $f:X\to Y $ is an homeomorphism then $\forall A\subset X, f|_A:A\to f(A)$ is an homeomorphism ?

I don't see the need to make that observation since it's pretty obvious to notice it, if  something works on the whole space $X$ then it's going to work too in a smaller set of $X$. Or am I missing something? Am I right in my reasoning?

Comment: As I always tell my students (typically right before I say that something is "obviously" true):  any time a mathematician says that something is obvious, they are lying.  What they really mean one of the following: (1) they are too lazy to prove it, (2) they think that you are to stupid for them to bother proving it for you, or (most commonly) (3) they don't actually know how to prove it themselves.  I am always deeply suspicious of "obvious" statements.  Here, the point is that you have to make sure that the subspace topology and the definition of a homeomorphism play nice together.

Comment: I had an argument once with my co-author. He said some observation was trivial and why make it. I said: never throw away good information, you don't know when you'll need it. As it turned out, that "trivial" observation turned out to be the key to the theorem in the next paper. So you never know.

Comment: I was not accusing you of lying.  The point is that "obvious" results are often not actually very obvious.  I know (more or less) what I am doing, and it took me 20 minutes to remember how to cobble together a sketch of the proof.  Any time that you are tempted to say that a result is "trivial," "obvious," or "clear," you really should sit down and make sure that it really is.  If so, great.  If not, you learned something new.

Comment: One more thing: do your exercises, they are good for you, whether you enjoy them or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can simply use the definition of the subspace topology on $A:$ it is the weakest one for which the insertion $i:A\to X$ is continuous. Then, $f|_A=f\circ i$. Now, if $V$ is open in $Y$, $(f\circ i)^{-1}(V)=i^{-1}\circ f^{-1}(V).$ Since $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X,\  i^{-1}( f^{-1}(V))$ is open in $A$ by definition of the subspace topology and so $f|_A$ is continuous.  The exact same reasoning shows that $(f|_A)^{-1}:f(A)\to A$ is continuous. Since $f|_A$ is bijective with inverse $(f|_A)^{-1}$, we conclude that $f|A$ is a homeomorphism onto $f(A).$

Answer (score 4):

You need to work on the subspace topologies: $\tau_{A}=\{A\cap G: G~\text{is open in }X\}$, $\tau_{f(A)}=\{f(A)\cap H: H~\text{is open in }Y\}$. Personally I don't think that is completely obvious, different topologies can turn continuity into discontinuity and open map to non-open map.

Answer (score 2):

To see that the restriction of a homeomorphism $\varphi : X\to Y$ to a set $A$ is a homeomorphism, we (at least naively) need to show three things:

1. $\varphi|_{A}$ is bijective,
2. $\varphi|_{A}$ is continuous, and
3. $(\varphi|_{A})^{-1}$ is continuous.

Typically, the first result should follow from more general arguments that have already been put forth.  However, for the sake of completeness, note that $\varphi|_{A}$ is surjective on $\varphi(A)$ by construction, and if $\varphi|_{A}(x) = \varphi|_{A}(y)$, then $\varphi(x) = \varphi(y)$, which implies that $x=y$ by the injectivity of $\varphi$.  Hence $\varphi|_{A}$ is injective.  This proves (1).

For (2), suppose that $V \subseteq \varphi(A)$ is open.  Then there is some open $V' \subseteq Y$ such that $V = V'\cap \varphi(A)$.  Since $\varphi$ is continuous, it follows that $\varphi^{-1}(V')$ is open.  On the other hand,
$$(\varphi|_{A})^{-1}(V) = \varphi^{-1}(V') \cap A. $$
But $\varphi$ is continuous, and so $\varphi^{-1}(V')$ is open.  This implies that $(\varphi|_{A})^{-1}(V)$ is open in the subspace topology on $A$, which further implies that $\varphi|_{A}$ is continuous, which completes the proof of (2).

The proof of (3) is, *mutatis mutandis*, the same as (2).  Indeed, we might summarize both (2) and (3) by the lemma

> **Lemma:**  The restriction of a continuous map $\varphi: X \to Y$ to a subspace $A \subseteq X$ is continuous.